# Serializing the Django object in the required format

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, extjs, django-models

I have a Storage model in which I get objects using serialization:

```
tree_data = serializers.serialize ("json", Storage.objects.all ())
```

It looks like this:

```
[
  {"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 9, "fields": {"code": "000", "name": "Title 1", "id_parent": 0}},
  {"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 10, "fields": {"code": "111", "name": "Test 1", "id_parent": 9}},
  {"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 11, "fields": {"code": "222", "name": "Test 2", "id_parent": 9}},
  {"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 12, "fields": {"code": "333", "name": "Title 2", "id_parent": 0}},
  {"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 13, "fields": {"code": "444", "name": "Test 3", "id_parent": 12}},
  {"model": "hello_extjs.storage", "pk": 14, "fields": {"code": "555", "name": "Test 4", "id_parent": 12}}

]
```

I need to have the data in this form:

```
{
    text: 'Storage',
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
        text: "Title 1",
        children: [{
            text: "Test 1",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "Test 2",
            leaf: true
        }],
        leaf: false,
        "expanded": true
    }, {
        text: "Title 2",
        children: [{
            text: "Test 3",
            leaf: true
        }, {
            text: "Test 4",
            leaf: true
        }],
        leaf: false,
        "expanded": true
    }]
}
```

How should I serialize objects to get the data in the form in which I need it?

Comment: It looks like you need to use a `Serializer` yes.

Comment: You should use [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), whose ModelSerializer classes can easily be configured to produce that output.

Comment: also I advice you to use MPTT library (https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html) if you did not do that yet for mother-child relations.

Comment: @DanielRoseman unless the OP really needs all the overhead of DRF, he might be better with a lighter lib like serpy (https://serpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers nice, hadn't encountered that library before.

Comment: @DanielRoseman wee're using it here (along with toastdriven's `restless` lib) and the combo is _much_ simpler and more flexible than DRF (imho of course).

Answer (score 1):

Django's builtin serializer is designed to meet Django's needs - dumping a whole queryset to a fixture and reloading that fixture, it won't - obviously - produce the very specific format you want. So the solution is simple: first write custom code producing the expected structure as a Python dict (containing only dicts, lists, strings, booleans and numerics - iow json compatible types) from your models, then pass it to `json.dumps()`. Problem solved.

Eventually you may want to look at something like [serpy](https://serpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to help with the custom serialization code...

Comment: So I need to go over the model objects in python and create the necessary dictionary structure, then use json.dumps () ?

Comment: @Ambasador basically: yes.

Comment: @ bruno desthuilliers I changed my question

Comment: you should roll back your edit and post a new question instead! Else the already posted answers dont make sense anymore. Please understanding that SO is not a support forum but a technical knowledge base.